# Passing a pointer to a class property

Tags: c#, properties, arguments, parameter-passing

**Edit:**  This is an example program, I understand that there is a sum operator in linq.  However, I was trying to ask specifically on how to pass the pointer to the property to do something complex with it, not necessarily this summing algorithm.

Lets say I have a class like this:

```
class Point
{
    double x {get; set;}
    double y {get; set;}
}
```

and in my main program I had 2 functions.

```
double function1(List<Point> PointList)
{
   double sum = 0.0;
   foreach(Point p in PointList)
   {
      sum += p.x;
   }       
   return sum;
}

double function2(List<Point> PointList)
{
   double sum = 0.0;
   foreach(Point p in PointList)
   {
      sum += p.y;
   }       
   return sum;
}
```

These functions are completely identical except one is summing the X values, the other is summing the Y values.  Since these are so similar, I would like to combine them such that I basically pass in that List of Points, and something to identify that I want to do the X or the Y based calculation.

I know I could put in a switch statement and tell it whether it was the X or the Y based on an enum, or a number that is defined to tell it to do the X or the Y.  If this was a normal function, I suppose I could use s delegate, but this is a property, so I'm not sure how that translates.

So how do I combine those functions into something like:

```
double bothFunctions(List<Point> PointList, var propertyToUse)
{
   double sum = 0.0;
   foreach(Point p in PointList)
   {
      sum += p.propertyToUse;
   }       
   return sum;
}
```

Where propertyToUse points to either X or Y.

Comment: The `PointList` obviously cannot be an `out` parameter. Are you sure this code is ok?

Comment: In my real program, it needs to be an out, but for this example, it does not, I'll remove that.

Comment: @Xantham in this case, a pointer is just a delegate. See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current solutions work great, but they assume either that your operation is `sum`, or that you will have only two possible properties (`X` and `Y`).

If you want more freedom, you can do:

```
double function(List<Point> PointList, Func<Point, double> selector)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    foreach (Point p in PointList)
    {
        sum += selector(p);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
double sumX = function(PointList, p => p.X);
double sumY = function(PointList, p => p.Y);
```

you'll be able to write more complicated selectors, like:

```
double sumXY = function(PointList, p => p.X + p.Y);
```

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I was looking for.  I will look more into this `Func` keyword.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Good. Read about `Func` and `Action`.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at using the [`Enumerable.Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549150.aspx) extension method instead of writing your own.

```
var sumX = pointList.Sum(item => item.X);
var sumY = pointList.Sum(item => item.Y);
```

You will need to add `using System.Linq;` if not already present in your code file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making it too complicated.  You can use a method like this:

```
double bothFunctions(List<Point> PointList, bool sumX)
{
   double sum = 0.0;
   foreach(Point p in PointList)
   {
      if (sumX)
          sum += p.x;
      else
          sum += p.y;
   }       
   return sum;
}
```

Or just use LINQ:

```
var ySum = pointList.Sum(e => e.y);
var xSum = pointList.Sum(e => e.x);
```